# Stop speaking this [language]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I think we should burninate [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language). Its tag description is practically a plea for removal:

> Don't use this tag. It is ambiguous, and too broad to be meaningful.

There are currently <s>414</s> [0 questions](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) with this tag, usually by new users. Most actually have the word "language" in the title. Here are some examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576284/generate-permutation-c-language -<- *language* in title

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566036/best-language-detectors-for-malay-language <- *language* in title

[Statement on different SQL Server with different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546207/statement-on-different-sql-server-with-different-languages) <- *languages* in title

Let's just remove this tag. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm currently editing and putting this for the summary: 'Tag description: "Don't use this tag. It is ambiguous, and too broad to be meaningful." See meta post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341315/get-rid-of-language '

Comment: Agreed; until there is a programming language called Language, this tag will likely be incredibly unclear/broad.

Comment: Well, that tag does have one obvious benefit: it allows us to easily find [questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519085/what-happened-to-this-string-ĩ҉̖̪̼͜ń̔̋ͮͪͬͪ̚̚%CD%8F̶͈͖̠͠v̧̖̯̫̟͊͐̄̕ȯ̞͉̼̍̐ͧ̿͒̋ͦ͜͝k͒̊).

Comment: There's also `Language-Lawyer` which I imagine could cover a lot of these

Comment: [tag:language-lawyer] has a very specific meaning. It is not a general replacement for questions tagged [tag:language].

Comment: You should probably read the tag wiki for [tag:burninate-request]. One of the things we prefer is that people with less than 2k rep don't flood the review queue with a bunch of tag edits...

Comment: "Watch your [language]" ;)

Comment: @TylerH Even if a programming language called Language appears, to avoid confusion something like [language-lang] might be preferable.

Comment: @Oriol Indeed! :-)

Comment: we need more [details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details)?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch  Think [tag:details] needs to be killed too?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch man, it was such a fine day... why did you have to ruin it (spoiler: the tag [tag:details] is a thing...)

Comment: @MDXF Please don't flood the review queue with tag-only edits. See Mike McCaughan's comment above.

Comment: @approxiblue he didn't edit the posts, he just edited the tag's wiki.

Comment: How about "Are we speaking the same [language]?"

Comment: Hey, @MikeMcCaughan your link is not pointing to the tag in meta. So he can't view the wiki from that link. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info

Comment: In case of programming languages, just use the relevant tag. That is just [C] and not [C][language]. In case of real-world languages, use [locale].

Comment: _"This kind of [language] is uncalled for"_

Comment: What to do for this kind of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994118/how-do-i-get-started-writing-a-computer-language which has only the [language] tag? I couldn't choose a tag for this closed question with 1 positive answer (so no roomba)

Comment: @Veve just close that crap.

Comment: @Braiam it was already closed ;)

Comment: @TylerH [There is.](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language) Just sayin'

Comment: @Challenger5 No known implementations. Looks like someone just wanted to be That Guy. At any rate, see Orion's comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart for the last question which has only this one, there isn't any `language` tag left. (I didn't found a good tag for it...)

Comment: I say we delete the question. It's off-topic anyway and preventing tag burnination.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, one of my questions had language as tag, because I was looking if there was a language that met certain requirements, therefore it was specifically targeted at languages. I think that in this case the language tag should be used.

**Edit**:

On second thought, in this case language-features and programming-languages might be better tags in this case. They are indeed less ambiguous

Comment: Aren't questions asking *if there was a language that meets certain requirements* off-topic anyway?

Comment: Which stack exchange would you post that on then? Since the number of StackExchange communities has grown exponentially since I started using it, I have no idea which would be the right one to use.

Comment: It may not be on-topic anywhere. There isn't a SE network for every question you could possibly come up with. For example, nowhere is it on-topic to ask, e.g. 'should I name my variable foobar or f00b4r?'

Comment: @MDXF Actually: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=variable+naming+convention . Also, to specify, I was talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369100/object-oriented-programming-language-with-seamless-graphics-card-accelleration-s

Comment: Regardless, *Don't use this tag. It is ambiguous, and too broad to be meaningful.*

Comment: ok I will use language-features and programming-languages then